# Hooking Up Portable Dishwasher in Kitchen with Pull Out Faucet

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchens, faucet, dishwasher

We recently bought a house that does not have a built in dishwasher. We have got a portable dishwasher and are considering how best to connect it to water.

[Currently, we have a Moen Pull Out Faucet.](https://imgur.com/iEqxSc1) Next to the faucet is an old soap dispenser that we would be fine with removing.

Down below, we have some soft hose going up to the faucet.

- [Picture 1](https://imgur.com/6LDrsvg)
- [Picture 2](https://imgur.com/EI7oL7m)

As I see it, there are four possibilities:

1. Pull off the head of the Moen faucet which reveals an end with threads. Get together several adaptors to make it fit the portable dishwasher and connect when the dishwasher is going. However, I have heard that the faucet and soft hose linings are not meant for the dishwasher pressure, and thus, damage could occur.
2. Remove the soap dispenser, and configure a faucet there that I can easily get the portable dishwasher attached to, and, run the necessary plumbing from the below area (just hotwater) to this faucet. I would need assistance figuring out what would be needed.
3. Just replace the Moen faucet with a more standard faucet. If possible, it would be nice to still have a sprayer.
4. Say that this is above my paygrade (I have limited experience), and call a plumber to check out how to do #2.

What option might you recommend for someone like me? I have the ability to follow instructions/youtube videos, and would like to learn how to do more of this.

Regarding Option 2 and 3, what instructions would you provide me to do this? Are there good resources like youtube videos that might fit this or other instructional material?

Comment: #1 should only require one adapter.  Our old dishwasher used a quick connect and we only had to change the plain aerator to one that fitted the quick connect of the dishwasher.  As long as both the faucet and the dishwasher connect are supported/held when connecting, it should be okay.

Comment: Yes, I think I could find one that would fit. I have read online (and seen the instructions on my own washer) that I shouldn't fit an adapter with the pull out faucet, as the pressure may be too much for the line? I don't know if that is true or not. If it isn't true, then I will just unscrew the wand and find an appropriate adaptor.

Comment: I would contact Moen.  They should know of any problems.  I can't see it since the water pressure should be the same, using the faucet alone or with a dishwasher, but the holder for the pull out might be different.

Comment: Here's the problem: "... I have heard that the faucet and soft hose linings are not meant for the dishwasher pressure, and thus, damage could occur." Yes, flexible hoses (for pull-out or separate sprayers) are prone to failure from the sudden shutoffs of the dishwasher water inlet. My GE portable says not to use it with a faucet with either pull-out or separate sprayer.

Comment: Is this portable d/w supposed to sit on the counter?  Personally, rather than fooling around with the faucet at all I'd just use the hole for the soap dispenser and run a hose down to the hot water shut-off valve with a tee.  Get yourself a soap bottle that sits on the counter (and if you don't want to sacrifice the dispenser hole, drill a new one in the sink deck).